# Object or With Variable Not Set

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub consolidateList()

    DeleteTableRows (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterSheet"))

    FillTableRows

End Sub

Private Sub FillTableRows()

    'set up worksheet objects
    Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkBookPath As String
    Set wkBook = ThisWorkbook
    wkBookPath = wkBook.Path


    Set wkSheet = wkBook.Worksheets("Master")

    'set up file system objects
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFiles As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(wkBookPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files


    'set up loop

    Dim checkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim reportDict As Dictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    'initial coordinates
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim startColumn As Long


    startColumn = 3

    Dim i As Long 'tracks within the row of the sheet where information is being pulled from
    Dim k As Long 'tracks the row where data is output on
    Dim j As Long 'tracks within the row of the sheet where the data is output on

    Dim Key As Variant

    j = 1
    k = wkSheet.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1


    Dim l As Long


    'look t Set checkBook = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)hrough folder and then save it to temp memory
    On Error GoTo debuger

        For Each oFile In oFiles
            startRow = 8


            'is it not the master sheet? check for duplicate entries
            'oFile.name is the name of the file being scanned


                'is it an excel file?
                If Mid(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name) - 3, 4) = ".xls" Or Mid(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name) - 3, 4) = ".xlsx" Then

                    Set checkBook = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)

                    For l = startRow To 600

                        If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(startRow, startColumn))) Then


                            'if it is, time do some calculations

                            Set reportDict = New Dictionary

                            'add items of the payment

                            For i = 0 To 33
                                If Not IsEmpty(Cells(startRow, startColumn + i)) Then
                                    reportDict.Add Cells(4, startColumn + i), Cells(startRow, startColumn + i)
                                End If
                            Next i


                            For i = startRow To 0 Step -1

                                    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, startColumn - 1)) Then
                                         reportDict.Add "Consumer Name", Cells(i, startColumn - 1)
                                         Exit For
                                    End If
                            Next i


                                'key is added
                                For Each Key In reportDict
                                    'wkSheet.Cells(k, j) = reportDict.Item(Key)


                                    Dim myInsert As Variant
                                    Set myInsert = reportDict.Item(Key)

                                    MsgBox (myInsert)

                                    wkSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(2, 1) = reportDict.Item(Key)
                                    j = j + 1

                                Next Key
                                    wkSheet.Cells(k, j) = wkSheet.Cells(k, 9) / 4
                                    wkSheet.Cells(k, j + 1) = oFile.Name
    '
                            k = k + 1

                         '   Set reportDict = Nothing
                            j = 1
                        Else
                            l = l + 1

                        End If
                        startRow = startRow + 1

                   Next l

                   checkBook.Close
                End If
        '        Exit For

        Next oFile


Exit Sub
debuger:
    MsgBox ("Error on: " & Err.Source & " in file " & oFile.Name & ", error is " & Err.Description)



End Sub


Sub DeleteTableRows(ByRef Table As ListObject)
    On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Clear Header Row `IF` it exists
    Table.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    '~~> Delete all the other rows `IF `they exist
    Table.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.count - 1, _
    Table.DataBodyRange.Columns.count).Rows.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Greetings. The above code consolidates a folder of data that's held on excel spreadsheets into one master excel spreadsheet. The goal is to run a macro on Excel Spreadsheet named master on the worksheet named master which opens up other excel workbooks in the folder, takes the information, and puts it into a table in the worksheet "master". After which point, it becomes easy to see the information; so instead of it being held on hundreds of worksheets, the records are held on one worksheet.

The code uses a dictionary (reportDict) to temporarily store the information that is needed from the individual workbooks. The goal then is to take that information and place it in the master table at the bottom row, and then obviously add a new row either after a successful placement or before an attempted placement of data.

The code fails at the following line:

```
wkSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(2, 1) = reportDict.Item(Key)
```

The failure description is "object or with variable not set" and so the issue is with the reportDict.Item(Key). My guess is that somehow VBA is not recognizing the dictionary item as stable, but I don't know how to correct this. Eventually the goal is to have code which does:

```
for each key in reportDict
  - place the item which is mapped to the key at a unique row,column in the master table
  - expand the table to accomodate necessary data
next key
```

Comment: Why would you use a variable called Key to iterate through the dictionary's Keys? Have you tried swapping out Key for k? e.g. dim k as variant, for each k in reportDict, etc.

Comment: If you're getting past the statement previous to your error line, which says `Set myInsert = reportDict.Item(Key)`, that indicates the problem is not necessarily with your dictionary. Can you create a `ListObject` variable and assign your table to it, in order to guarantee you have a valid table on the sheet?

Comment: `wkBook` is redundant, it's `ThisWorkbook`, which means you're referring to *the workbook that's executing this code*, which means `wkSheet` is likely redundant as well - give it a *code name* (F4 and edit its `(Name)` property, e.g. `MasterSheet`) and use that identifier instead: `MasterSheet.Range(...)` becomes legal code, and you just removed the need to dereference a compile-time existing worksheet at run-time.

Comment: Your code can't possibly run as-is. `DeleteTableRows (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterSheet"))` is a compile-time type mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit default member calls are plaguing your code all over.

```
reportDict.Add Cells(4, startColumn + i), Cells(startRow, startColumn + i)
```

That's implicitly accessing `Range.[_Default]` off whatever worksheet is currently the `ActiveSheet` (did you mean that to be `wkSheet.Cells`?), to get the `Key` - since the `Key` parameter is a `String`, `Range.[_Default]` is implicitly coerced into one, and you have a string key. The actual dictionary item at that key though, isn't as lucky.

Here's a MCVE:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim d As Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary
    d.Add "A1", Cells(1, 1)
    Debug.Print IsObject(d("A1"))
End Sub
```

This procedure prints `True` to the debug pane (Ctrl+G): what you're storing in your dictionary isn't a bunch of string values, but a bunch of `Range` object references.

So when you do this:

```
Dim myInsert As Variant
Set myInsert = reportDict.Item(Key)
```

You might as well have declared `myInsert As Range`, for it is one.

This is where things get interesting:

```
MsgBox (myInsert)
```

Nevermind the superfluous parentheses that force-evaluate the object's default member and pass it `ByVal` to the `MsgBox` function - here you're implicitly converting `Range.[_Default]` into a `String`. That probably works.

So why is this failing then?

```
wkSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(2, 1) = reportDict.Item(Key)
```

Normally, it wouldn't. VBA would happily do this:

```
wkSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 1).[_Default] = reportDict.Item(Key).[_Default]
```

And write the value in the `DataBodyRange` of the `ListObject` at the specified location.

**I think that's all just red herring. Write explicit code: if you mean to store the `Value` of a cell, *store the `Value` of a cell*. If you mean to assign the `Value` of a cell, *assign the `Value` of a cell***.

I can't replicate error 91 with this setup.

This, however:

```
DeleteTableRows (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterSheet"))
```

...is *also* force-evaluating a `ListObject`'s default member - so `DeleteTableRows` isn't receiving a `ListObject`, it's getting a `String` that contains the name of the object you've just dereferenced... but `DeleteTableRows` takes a `ListObject` parameter, so there's no way that code can even *get* to run `FillTableRows` - it has to blow up with a *type mismatch* before `DeleteTableRows` even gets to enter. In fact, **it's a compile-time error**.

So this is a rather long answer that doesn't get to the reason for error 91 on that specific line (I can't reproduce it), but highlights a metric ton of serious problems with your code that *very likely* **are** related to this error you're getting. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi yes thank you. It turns out that while yes it was a problem, the problem is that I really didn't have any ideas about  how tables in excel work. So I was trying to add information to a table which did not have any rows, even though those rows were visually displayed on my spreadsheet.

Comment: In the future please make sure the code you're posting actually reproduces the problem you're asking about. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the dictionary's Keys collection.

```
dim k as variant, myInsert As Variant

for each k in reportDict.keys
    debug.print reportDict.Item(k)
next k
```